# Good-looking logic derivation

Tags: logic, logicproof

I'm doing derivations for a logic class and I'd like my diagrams to look something like this:
[image]

Here is my attempt with the `natded` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

% https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/natded/natded.pdf
\usepackage{natded}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\Jproof {
        \vspace{-0.25cm}
        \proofline {\text{\st{Show} } P \to \lnot R}{}
        \cablk {
            \proofline {P}{ass cd}
            \proofline {\text{\st{Show} } \lnot R}{}
            \cablk {
                \proofline {\lnot Q}{pr1 2 mp}
                \proofline {\lnot R}{pr2 4 mt}
                \proofline { }{5 dd}
            }
            \proofline { }{3 cd}
        }}$
\end{document}
```

The above is rendered as this:
[image]

It's not quite ideal as the spacing of each line isn't even, and the nested boxes leave too much space in between them.

Here is an example using the `logicproof` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

% http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/logicproof/logicproof.pdf
\usepackage{logicproof}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{logicproof}{2}
    \text{\st{Show} } P \to \lnot R & \\
    \begin{subproof}
        P & ass cd \\
        \text{\st{Show} } \lnot R & \\
        \begin{subproof}
            \lnot Q & pr1 2 mp \\
            \lnot R & pr2 4 mt \\
            & 5 dd
        \end{subproof}
        & 3 cd
    \end{subproof}
\end{logicproof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The boxes are nicely spaced and the lines are even. However, I'm not sure if it supports indentations out of the box and it cannot end on an empty line after a subproof. Can anyone help out with either fixing the `natded` example, or making the `logicproof` example useable? Thanks for reading!